# How to get the tag text in this case?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I'm struggling to get the content of the tag `<text>`

```js
$( "svg" ).click(function(e) {
    console.log("we are in the svg element");
    //console.log(e.target.next("text"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" contentScriptType="application/ecmascript" contentStyleType="text/css" height="555px" preserveAspectRatio="none" style="width:1181px;height:555px;" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 1181 555" width="1181px" zoomAndPan="magnify">
  <defs>
  <filter height="300%" id="fowbx44" width="300%" x="-1" y="-1">  <feGaussianBlur result="blurOut" stdDeviation="2.0"/><feColorMatrix in="blurOut" result="blurOut2" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 .4 0"/><feOffset dx="4.0" dy="4.0" in="blurOut2" result="blurOut3"/><feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="blurOut3" mode="normal"/>
  </filter>
  </defs>

  <g>
  <!--entity cadvisor-->
  <rect fill="#FEFECE" filter="url(#fowbx44)" height="46.29" style="stroke:     #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="97" x="133.675" y="8"/><rect           fill="#FEFECE" height="10" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;"     width="15" x="210.675" y="13"/>
  <rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width:         1.5;" width="4" x="208.675" y="15"/>
  <rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="208.675" y="19"/>
  <text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="57" x="148.675" y="41.3027">cadvisor
  </text>
  <!--entity cleanup--><rect fill="#FEFECE" filter="url(#fowbx44)" height="46.29" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="94" x="266.175" y="8"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="10" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="15" x="340.175" y="13"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="338.175" y="15"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="338.175" y="19"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="54" x="281.175" y="41.3027">cleanup</text><!--entity cmdb-db--><rect fill="#FEFECE" filter="url(#fowbx44)" height="46.29" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="104" x="433.175" y="377"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="10" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="15" x="517.175" y="382"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="515.175" y="384"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="515.175" y="388"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="64" x="448.175" y="410.3027">cmdb-db</text><!--entity cmdb-web--><rect fill="#FEFECE" filter="url(#fowbx44)" height="46.29" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="114" x="392.175" y="254"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="10" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="15" x="486.175" y="259"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="484.175" y="261"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="484.175" y="265"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="74" x="407.175" y="287.3027">cmdb-web</text><!--entity elasticsearch--><rect fill="#FEFECE" filter="url(#fowbx44)" height="46.29" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="128" x="270.175" y="377"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="10" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="15" x="378.175" y="382"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="376.175" y="384"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="376.175" y="388"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="88" x="285.175" y="410.3027">elasticsearch</text><!--entity guacamole--><rect fill="#FEFECE" filter="url(#fowbx44)" height="46.29" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="115" x="755.675" y="131"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="10" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="15" x="850.675" y="136"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="848.675" y="138"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="848.675" y="142"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="75" x="770.675" y="164.3027">guacamole</text><!--entity guacd--><rect fill="#FEFECE" filter="url(#fowbx44)" height="46.29" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="82" x="772.175" y="254"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="10" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="15" x="834.175" y="259"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="832.175" y="261"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="832.175" y="265"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="42" x="787.175" y="287.3027">guacd</text><!--entity init-area-pw--><rect fill="#FEFECE" filter="url(#fowbx44)" height="46.29" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="128" x="106.175" y="500"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="10" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="15" x="214.175" y="505"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="212.175" y="507"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="212.175" y="511"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="88" x="121.175" y="533.3027">init-area-pw</text><!--entity nginx-proxy--><rect fill="#FEFECE" filter="url(#fowbx44)" height="46.29" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="128" x="395.175" y="8"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="10" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="15" x="503.175" y="13"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="501.175" y="15"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="501.175" y="19"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="88" x="410.175" y="41.3027">nginx-proxy</text><!--entity nodeexporter--><rect fill="#FEFECE" filter="url(#fowbx44)" height="46.29" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="135" x="114.675" y="131"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="10" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="15" x="229.675" y="136"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="227.675" y="138"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="227.675" y="142"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="95" x="129.675" y="164.3027">nodeexporter</text><!--entity opennms-appl--><rect fill="#FEFECE" filter="url(#fowbx44)" height="46.29" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="142" x="99.1751" y="254"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="10" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="15" x="221.1751" y="259"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="219.1751" y="261"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="219.1751" y="265"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="102" x="114.1751" y="287.3027">opennms-appl</text><!--entity opennms-db--><rect fill="#FEFECE" filter="url(#fowbx44)" height="46.29" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="130" x="105.1751" y="377"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="10" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="15" x="215.1751" y="382"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="213.1751" y="384"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="213.1751" y="388"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="90" x="120.1751" y="410.3027">opennms-db</text><!--entity portal-app--><rect fill="#FEFECE" filter="url(#fowbx44)" height="46.29" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="115" x="905.675" y="131"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="10" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="15" x="1000.675" y="136"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="998.675" y="138"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="998.675" y="142"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="75" x="920.675" y="164.3027">portal-app</text><!--entity portal-mongo--><rect fill="#FEFECE" filter="url(#fowbx44)" height="46.29" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="138" x="1034.18" y="254"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="10" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="15" x="1152.18" y="259"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="1150.18" y="261"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="1150.18" y="265"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="98" x="1049.18" y="287.3027">portal-mongo</text><!--entity portal-web--><rect fill="#FEFECE" filter="url(#fowbx44)" height="46.29" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="117" x="829.675" y="8"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="10" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="15" x="926.675" y="13"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="924.675" y="15"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="924.675" y="19"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="77" x="844.675" y="41.3027">portal-web</text><!--entity prometheus--><rect fill="#FEFECE" filter="url(#fowbx44)" height="46.29" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="123" x="284.675" y="131"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="10" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="15" x="387.675" y="136"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="385.675" y="138"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="385.675" y="142"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="83" x="299.675" y="164.3027">prometheus</text><!--entity rab_opennms--><rect fill="#FEFECE" filter="url(#fowbx44)" height="46.29" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="134" x="443.175" y="131"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="10" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="15" x="557.175" y="136"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="555.175" y="138"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="555.175" y="142"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="94" x="458.175" y="164.3027">rab_opennms</text><!--entity rabbitmq--><rect fill="#FEFECE" filter="url(#fowbx44)" height="46.29" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="103" x="648.675" y="377"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="10" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="15" x="731.675" y="382"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="729.675" y="384"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="729.675" y="388"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="63" x="663.675" y="410.3027">rabbitmq</text><path d="M433.159,420.981 C378.09,442.134 291.18,475.5186 232.489,498.0635 " fill="none" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.0; stroke-dasharray: 7.0,7.0;"/><polygon fill="#A80036" points="227.608,499.9386,237.4439,500.4428,232.275,498.1445,234.5733,492.9755,227.608,499.9386" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.0;"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="13" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="73" x="347.175" y="466.3525">depends on</text><path d="M444.27,300.002 C442.139,313.838 441.132,331.871 446.175,347 C449.216,356.123 454.554,364.935 460.323,372.631 " fill="none" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.0; stroke-dasharray: 7.0,7.0;"/><polygon fill="#A80036" points="463.561,376.787,461.1853,367.229,460.4881,372.8427,454.8744,372.1456,463.561,376.787" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.0;"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="13" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="73" x="447.175" y="343.3525">depends on</text><path d="M396.942,300.062 C383.193,307.877 369.372,317.826 359.175,330 C349.193,341.918 343.047,358.15 339.348,371.876 " fill="none" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.0; stroke-dasharray: 7.0,7.0;"/><polygon fill="#A80036" points="338.093,376.807,344.1886,369.0711,339.3258,371.9614,336.4356,367.0986,338.093,376.807" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.0;"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="13" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="73" x="360.175" y="343.3525">depends on</text><path d="M481.541,300.271 C503.41,314.728 533.276,333.348 561.175,347 C587.646,359.953 618.212,371.712 643.928,380.758 " fill="none" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.0; stroke-dasharray: 7.0,7.0;"/><polygon fill="#A80036" points="648.671,382.415,641.4933,375.6711,643.9506,380.7663,638.8554,383.2236,648.671,382.415" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.0;"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="13" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="73" x="562.175" y="343.3525">depends on</text><path d="M813.175,177.193 C813.175,197.405 813.175,227.307 813.175,248.919 " fill="none" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.0; stroke-dasharray: 7.0,7.0;"/><polygon fill="#A80036" points="813.175,253.947,817.175,244.947,813.175,248.947,809.175,244.947,813.175,253.947" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.0;"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="13" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="73" x="814.175" y="220.3525">depends on</text><path d="M792.449,300.193 C773.175,320.832 744.466,351.573 724.199,373.275 " fill="none" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.0; stroke-dasharray: 7.0,7.0;"/><polygon fill="#A80036" points="720.77,376.947,729.8363,373.0997,724.1828,373.2928,723.9896,367.6393,720.77,376.947" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.0;"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="13" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="73" x="764.175" y="343.3525">depends on</text><path d="M107.419,300.047 C72.9622,315.749 33.2533,340.602 13.1751,377 C-15.4127,428.823 52.5835,472.3619 107.899,497.8191 " fill="none" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.0; stroke-dasharray: 7.0,7.0;"/><polygon fill="#A80036" points="112.531,499.923,105.99,492.5599,107.9783,497.8558,102.6825,499.8442,112.531,499.923" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.0;"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="13" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="73" x="14.1751" y="404.8525">depends on</text><path d="M170.175,300.193 C170.175,320.405 170.175,350.307 170.175,371.919 " fill="none" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.0; stroke-dasharray: 7.0,7.0;"/><polygon fill="#A80036" points="170.175,376.947,174.175,367.947,170.175,371.947,166.175,367.947,170.175,376.947" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.0;"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="13" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="73" x="171.175" y="343.3525">depends on</text><path d="M170.175,423.193 C170.175,443.405 170.175,473.3072 170.175,494.9188 " fill="none" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.0; stroke-dasharray: 7.0,7.0;"/><polygon fill="#A80036" points="170.175,499.9474,174.175,490.9474,170.175,494.9474,166.175,490.9474,170.175,499.9474" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.0;"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="13" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="73" x="171.175" y="466.3525">depends on</text><path d="M988.853,177.193 C1012.83,197.917 1048.6,228.827 1073.72,250.544 " fill="none" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.0; stroke-dasharray: 7.0,7.0;"/><polygon fill="#A80036" points="1077.66,253.947,1073.469,245.0343,1073.8781,250.6764,1068.236,251.0854,1077.66,253.947" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.0;"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="13" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="73" x="1042.18" y="220.3525">depends on</text><path d="M955.446,177.06 C940.484,216.67 903.864,300.079 846.175,347 C820.523,367.865 785.855,380.68 756.738,388.367 " fill="none" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.0; stroke-dasharray: 7.0,7.0;"/><polygon fill="#A80036" points="751.743,389.65,761.4553,391.2845,756.5857,388.4058,759.4645,383.5362,751.743,389.65" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.0;"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="13" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="73" x="920.175" y="281.8525">depends on</text><path d="M861.526,54.041 C852.478,62.623 842.954,73.031 836.175,84 C828.322,96.707 822.815,112.404 819.164,125.614 " fill="none" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.0; stroke-dasharray: 7.0,7.0;"/><polygon fill="#A80036" points="817.806,130.731,823.9812,123.0585,819.0888,125.8984,816.2489,121.006,817.806,130.731" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.0;"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="13" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="73" x="837.175" y="97.3525">depends on</text><path d="M901.931,54.193 C914.565,74.576 933.307,104.813 946.727,126.464 " fill="none" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.0; stroke-dasharray: 7.0,7.0;"/><polygon fill="#A80036" points="949.506,130.947,948.1643,121.19,946.8718,126.6972,941.3646,125.4046,949.506,130.947" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.0;"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="13" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="73" x="930.175" y="97.3525">depends on</text><path d="M448.209,177.053 C388.38,198.345 298.068,230.485 236.735,252.312 " fill="none" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.0; stroke-dasharray: 7.0,7.0;"/><polygon fill="#A80036" points="232.002,253.997,241.8221,254.7488,236.7127,252.321,239.1406,247.2116,232.002,253.997" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.0;"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="13" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="73" x="361.175" y="220.3525">depends on</text><path d="M527.371,177.084 C562.397,222.064 641.875,324.13 679.583,372.555 " fill="none" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.0; stroke-dasharray: 7.0,7.0;"/><polygon fill="#A80036" points="682.881,376.79,680.5053,367.232,679.8081,372.8457,674.1944,372.1486,682.881,376.79" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.0;"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="13" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="73" x="621.175" y="281.8525">depends on</text></g></svg>
```

So I want to get the `<text>` value of each container we click on but I can't use `next` because I got an error

Comment: What was the error? Can you put it in the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to handle both clicking the `text` itself **and** clicking the `rect` it appears to be within, you can do that by checking what you clicked and, if it's a `rect`, get the `text` that follows, like so:

```
$( "svg" ).click(function(e) {
    var elm = e.target.tagName === "text"
      ? $(e.target)
      : $(e.target).nextAll("text").first();
    console.log(elm.text());
});
```

Example:

```js
$( "svg" ).click(function(e) {
    var elm = e.target.tagName === "text"
      ? $(e.target)
      : $(e.target).nextAll("text").first();
    console.log(elm.text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" contentScriptType="application/ecmascript" contentStyleType="text/css" height="555px" preserveAspectRatio="none" style="width:1181px;height:555px;" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 1181 555" width="1181px" zoomAndPan="magnify">
  <defs>
  <filter height="300%" id="fowbx44" width="300%" x="-1" y="-1">  <feGaussianBlur result="blurOut" stdDeviation="2.0"/><feColorMatrix in="blurOut" result="blurOut2" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 .4 0"/><feOffset dx="4.0" dy="4.0" in="blurOut2" result="blurOut3"/><feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="blurOut3" mode="normal"/>
  </filter>
  </defs>

  <g>
  <!--entity cadvisor-->
  <rect fill="#FEFECE" filter="url(#fowbx44)" height="46.29" style="stroke:     #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="97" x="133.675" y="8"/><rect           fill="#FEFECE" height="10" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;"     width="15" x="210.675" y="13"/>
  <rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width:         1.5;" width="4" x="208.675" y="15"/>
  <rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="208.675" y="19"/>
  <text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="57" x="148.675" y="41.3027">cadvisor
  </text>
  <!--entity cleanup--><rect fill="#FEFECE" filter="url(#fowbx44)" height="46.29" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="94" x="266.175" y="8"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="10" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="15" x="340.175" y="13"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="338.175" y="15"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="338.175" y="19"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="54" x="281.175" y="41.3027">cleanup</text><!--entity cmdb-db--><rect fill="#FEFECE" filter="url(#fowbx44)" height="46.29" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="104" x="433.175" y="377"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="10" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="15" x="517.175" y="382"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="515.175" y="384"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="515.175" y="388"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="64" x="448.175" y="410.3027">cmdb-db</text><!--entity cmdb-web--><rect fill="#FEFECE" filter="url(#fowbx44)" height="46.29" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="114" x="392.175" y="254"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="10" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="15" x="486.175" y="259"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="484.175" y="261"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="484.175" y="265"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="74" x="407.175" y="287.3027">cmdb-web</text><!--entity elasticsearch--><rect fill="#FEFECE" filter="url(#fowbx44)" height="46.29" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="128" x="270.175" y="377"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="10" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="15" x="378.175" y="382"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="376.175" y="384"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="376.175" y="388"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="88" x="285.175" y="410.3027">elasticsearch</text><!--entity guacamole--><rect fill="#FEFECE" filter="url(#fowbx44)" height="46.29" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="115" x="755.675" y="131"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="10" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="15" x="850.675" y="136"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="848.675" y="138"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="848.675" y="142"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="75" x="770.675" y="164.3027">guacamole</text><!--entity guacd--><rect fill="#FEFECE" filter="url(#fowbx44)" height="46.29" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="82" x="772.175" y="254"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="10" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="15" x="834.175" y="259"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="832.175" y="261"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="832.175" y="265"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="42" x="787.175" y="287.3027">guacd</text><!--entity init-area-pw--><rect fill="#FEFECE" filter="url(#fowbx44)" height="46.29" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="128" x="106.175" y="500"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="10" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="15" x="214.175" y="505"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="212.175" y="507"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="212.175" y="511"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="88" x="121.175" y="533.3027">init-area-pw</text><!--entity nginx-proxy--><rect fill="#FEFECE" filter="url(#fowbx44)" height="46.29" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="128" x="395.175" y="8"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="10" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="15" x="503.175" y="13"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="501.175" y="15"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="501.175" y="19"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="88" x="410.175" y="41.3027">nginx-proxy</text><!--entity nodeexporter--><rect fill="#FEFECE" filter="url(#fowbx44)" height="46.29" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="135" x="114.675" y="131"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="10" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="15" x="229.675" y="136"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="227.675" y="138"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="227.675" y="142"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="95" x="129.675" y="164.3027">nodeexporter</text><!--entity opennms-appl--><rect fill="#FEFECE" filter="url(#fowbx44)" height="46.29" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="142" x="99.1751" y="254"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="10" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="15" x="221.1751" y="259"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="219.1751" y="261"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="219.1751" y="265"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="102" x="114.1751" y="287.3027">opennms-appl</text><!--entity opennms-db--><rect fill="#FEFECE" filter="url(#fowbx44)" height="46.29" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="130" x="105.1751" y="377"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="10" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="15" x="215.1751" y="382"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="213.1751" y="384"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="213.1751" y="388"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="90" x="120.1751" y="410.3027">opennms-db</text><!--entity portal-app--><rect fill="#FEFECE" filter="url(#fowbx44)" height="46.29" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="115" x="905.675" y="131"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="10" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="15" x="1000.675" y="136"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="998.675" y="138"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="998.675" y="142"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="75" x="920.675" y="164.3027">portal-app</text><!--entity portal-mongo--><rect fill="#FEFECE" filter="url(#fowbx44)" height="46.29" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="138" x="1034.18" y="254"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="10" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="15" x="1152.18" y="259"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="1150.18" y="261"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="1150.18" y="265"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="98" x="1049.18" y="287.3027">portal-mongo</text><!--entity portal-web--><rect fill="#FEFECE" filter="url(#fowbx44)" height="46.29" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="117" x="829.675" y="8"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="10" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="15" x="926.675" y="13"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="924.675" y="15"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="924.675" y="19"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="77" x="844.675" y="41.3027">portal-web</text><!--entity prometheus--><rect fill="#FEFECE" filter="url(#fowbx44)" height="46.29" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="123" x="284.675" y="131"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="10" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="15" x="387.675" y="136"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="385.675" y="138"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="385.675" y="142"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="83" x="299.675" y="164.3027">prometheus</text><!--entity rab_opennms--><rect fill="#FEFECE" filter="url(#fowbx44)" height="46.29" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="134" x="443.175" y="131"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="10" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="15" x="557.175" y="136"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="555.175" y="138"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="555.175" y="142"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="94" x="458.175" y="164.3027">rab_opennms</text><!--entity rabbitmq--><rect fill="#FEFECE" filter="url(#fowbx44)" height="46.29" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="103" x="648.675" y="377"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="10" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="15" x="731.675" y="382"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="729.675" y="384"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="729.675" y="388"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="63" x="663.675" y="410.3027">rabbitmq</text><path d="M433.159,420.981 C378.09,442.134 291.18,475.5186 232.489,498.0635 " fill="none" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.0; stroke-dasharray: 7.0,7.0;"/><polygon fill="#A80036" points="227.608,499.9386,237.4439,500.4428,232.275,498.1445,234.5733,492.9755,227.608,499.9386" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.0;"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="13" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="73" x="347.175" y="466.3525">depends on</text><path d="M444.27,300.002 C442.139,313.838 441.132,331.871 446.175,347 C449.216,356.123 454.554,364.935 460.323,372.631 " fill="none" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.0; stroke-dasharray: 7.0,7.0;"/><polygon fill="#A80036" points="463.561,376.787,461.1853,367.229,460.4881,372.8427,454.8744,372.1456,463.561,376.787" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.0;"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="13" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="73" x="447.175" y="343.3525">depends on</text><path d="M396.942,300.062 C383.193,307.877 369.372,317.826 359.175,330 C349.193,341.918 343.047,358.15 339.348,371.876 " fill="none" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.0; stroke-dasharray: 7.0,7.0;"/><polygon fill="#A80036" points="338.093,376.807,344.1886,369.0711,339.3258,371.9614,336.4356,367.0986,338.093,376.807" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.0;"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="13" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="73" x="360.175" y="343.3525">depends on</text><path d="M481.541,300.271 C503.41,314.728 533.276,333.348 561.175,347 C587.646,359.953 618.212,371.712 643.928,380.758 " fill="none" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.0; stroke-dasharray: 7.0,7.0;"/><polygon fill="#A80036" points="648.671,382.415,641.4933,375.6711,643.9506,380.7663,638.8554,383.2236,648.671,382.415" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.0;"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="13" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="73" x="562.175" y="343.3525">depends on</text><path d="M813.175,177.193 C813.175,197.405 813.175,227.307 813.175,248.919 " fill="none" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.0; stroke-dasharray: 7.0,7.0;"/><polygon fill="#A80036" points="813.175,253.947,817.175,244.947,813.175,248.947,809.175,244.947,813.175,253.947" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.0;"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="13" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="73" x="814.175" y="220.3525">depends on</text><path d="M792.449,300.193 C773.175,320.832 744.466,351.573 724.199,373.275 " fill="none" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.0; stroke-dasharray: 7.0,7.0;"/><polygon fill="#A80036" points="720.77,376.947,729.8363,373.0997,724.1828,373.2928,723.9896,367.6393,720.77,376.947" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.0;"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="13" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="73" x="764.175" y="343.3525">depends on</text><path d="M107.419,300.047 C72.9622,315.749 33.2533,340.602 13.1751,377 C-15.4127,428.823 52.5835,472.3619 107.899,497.8191 " fill="none" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.0; stroke-dasharray: 7.0,7.0;"/><polygon fill="#A80036" points="112.531,499.923,105.99,492.5599,107.9783,497.8558,102.6825,499.8442,112.531,499.923" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.0;"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="13" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="73" x="14.1751" y="404.8525">depends on</text><path d="M170.175,300.193 C170.175,320.405 170.175,350.307 170.175,371.919 " fill="none" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.0; stroke-dasharray: 7.0,7.0;"/><polygon fill="#A80036" points="170.175,376.947,174.175,367.947,170.175,371.947,166.175,367.947,170.175,376.947" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.0;"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="13" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="73" x="171.175" y="343.3525">depends on</text><path d="M170.175,423.193 C170.175,443.405 170.175,473.3072 170.175,494.9188 " fill="none" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.0; stroke-dasharray: 7.0,7.0;"/><polygon fill="#A80036" points="170.175,499.9474,174.175,490.9474,170.175,494.9474,166.175,490.9474,170.175,499.9474" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.0;"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="13" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="73" x="171.175" y="466.3525">depends on</text><path d="M988.853,177.193 C1012.83,197.917 1048.6,228.827 1073.72,250.544 " fill="none" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.0; stroke-dasharray: 7.0,7.0;"/><polygon fill="#A80036" points="1077.66,253.947,1073.469,245.0343,1073.8781,250.6764,1068.236,251.0854,1077.66,253.947" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.0;"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="13" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="73" x="1042.18" y="220.3525">depends on</text><path d="M955.446,177.06 C940.484,216.67 903.864,300.079 846.175,347 C820.523,367.865 785.855,380.68 756.738,388.367 " fill="none" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.0; stroke-dasharray: 7.0,7.0;"/><polygon fill="#A80036" points="751.743,389.65,761.4553,391.2845,756.5857,388.4058,759.4645,383.5362,751.743,389.65" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.0;"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="13" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="73" x="920.175" y="281.8525">depends on</text><path d="M861.526,54.041 C852.478,62.623 842.954,73.031 836.175,84 C828.322,96.707 822.815,112.404 819.164,125.614 " fill="none" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.0; stroke-dasharray: 7.0,7.0;"/><polygon fill="#A80036" points="817.806,130.731,823.9812,123.0585,819.0888,125.8984,816.2489,121.006,817.806,130.731" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.0;"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="13" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="73" x="837.175" y="97.3525">depends on</text><path d="M901.931,54.193 C914.565,74.576 933.307,104.813 946.727,126.464 " fill="none" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.0; stroke-dasharray: 7.0,7.0;"/><polygon fill="#A80036" points="949.506,130.947,948.1643,121.19,946.8718,126.6972,941.3646,125.4046,949.506,130.947" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.0;"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="13" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="73" x="930.175" y="97.3525">depends on</text><path d="M448.209,177.053 C388.38,198.345 298.068,230.485 236.735,252.312 " fill="none" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.0; stroke-dasharray: 7.0,7.0;"/><polygon fill="#A80036" points="232.002,253.997,241.8221,254.7488,236.7127,252.321,239.1406,247.2116,232.002,253.997" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.0;"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="13" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="73" x="361.175" y="220.3525">depends on</text><path d="M527.371,177.084 C562.397,222.064 641.875,324.13 679.583,372.555 " fill="none" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.0; stroke-dasharray: 7.0,7.0;"/><polygon fill="#A80036" points="682.881,376.79,680.5053,367.232,679.8081,372.8457,674.1944,372.1486,682.881,376.79" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.0;"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="13" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="73" x="621.175" y="281.8525">depends on</text></g></svg>
```

Comment: Your answer is a bit better than the one of @Carsten but I don't know which one marking as the right answer

Answer (score 5):

Use `$("svg text")` to select the text you are clicking on inside your svg.

Then use `$(this).text()` to get the text

```js
$("svg text").click(function() {
  console.log($(this).text())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" contentScriptType="application/ecmascript" contentStyleType="text/css" height="555px" preserveAspectRatio="none" style="width:1181px;height:555px;" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 1181 555" width="1181px" zoomAndPan="magnify">
  <defs>
  <filter height="300%" id="fowbx44" width="300%" x="-1" y="-1">  <feGaussianBlur result="blurOut" stdDeviation="2.0"/><feColorMatrix in="blurOut" result="blurOut2" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 .4 0"/><feOffset dx="4.0" dy="4.0" in="blurOut2" result="blurOut3"/><feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="blurOut3" mode="normal"/>
  </filter>
  </defs>

  <g>
  <!--entity cadvisor-->
  <rect fill="#FEFECE" filter="url(#fowbx44)" height="46.29" style="stroke:     #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="97" x="133.675" y="8"/><rect           fill="#FEFECE" height="10" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;"     width="15" x="210.675" y="13"/>
  <rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width:         1.5;" width="4" x="208.675" y="15"/>
  <rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="208.675" y="19"/>
  <text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="57" x="148.675" y="41.3027">cadvisor
  </text>
  <!--entity cleanup--><rect fill="#FEFECE" filter="url(#fowbx44)" height="46.29" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="94" x="266.175" y="8"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="10" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="15" x="340.175" y="13"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="338.175" y="15"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="338.175" y="19"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="54" x="281.175" y="41.3027">cleanup</text><!--entity cmdb-db--><rect fill="#FEFECE" filter="url(#fowbx44)" height="46.29" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="104" x="433.175" y="377"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="10" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="15" x="517.175" y="382"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="515.175" y="384"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="515.175" y="388"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="64" x="448.175" y="410.3027">cmdb-db</text><!--entity cmdb-web--><rect fill="#FEFECE" filter="url(#fowbx44)" height="46.29" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="114" x="392.175" y="254"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="10" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="15" x="486.175" y="259"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="484.175" y="261"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="484.175" y="265"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="74" x="407.175" y="287.3027">cmdb-web</text><!--entity elasticsearch--><rect fill="#FEFECE" filter="url(#fowbx44)" height="46.29" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="128" x="270.175" y="377"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="10" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="15" x="378.175" y="382"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="376.175" y="384"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="376.175" y="388"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="88" x="285.175" y="410.3027">elasticsearch</text><!--entity guacamole--><rect fill="#FEFECE" filter="url(#fowbx44)" height="46.29" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="115" x="755.675" y="131"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="10" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="15" x="850.675" y="136"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="848.675" y="138"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="848.675" y="142"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="75" x="770.675" y="164.3027">guacamole</text><!--entity guacd--><rect fill="#FEFECE" filter="url(#fowbx44)" height="46.29" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="82" x="772.175" y="254"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="10" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="15" x="834.175" y="259"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="832.175" y="261"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="832.175" y="265"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="42" x="787.175" y="287.3027">guacd</text><!--entity init-area-pw--><rect fill="#FEFECE" filter="url(#fowbx44)" height="46.29" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="128" x="106.175" y="500"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="10" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="15" x="214.175" y="505"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="212.175" y="507"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="212.175" y="511"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="88" x="121.175" y="533.3027">init-area-pw</text><!--entity nginx-proxy--><rect fill="#FEFECE" filter="url(#fowbx44)" height="46.29" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="128" x="395.175" y="8"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="10" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="15" x="503.175" y="13"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="501.175" y="15"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="501.175" y="19"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="88" x="410.175" y="41.3027">nginx-proxy</text><!--entity nodeexporter--><rect fill="#FEFECE" filter="url(#fowbx44)" height="46.29" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="135" x="114.675" y="131"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="10" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="15" x="229.675" y="136"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="227.675" y="138"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="227.675" y="142"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="95" x="129.675" y="164.3027">nodeexporter</text><!--entity opennms-appl--><rect fill="#FEFECE" filter="url(#fowbx44)" height="46.29" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="142" x="99.1751" y="254"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="10" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="15" x="221.1751" y="259"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="219.1751" y="261"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="219.1751" y="265"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="102" x="114.1751" y="287.3027">opennms-appl</text><!--entity opennms-db--><rect fill="#FEFECE" filter="url(#fowbx44)" height="46.29" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="130" x="105.1751" y="377"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="10" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="15" x="215.1751" y="382"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="213.1751" y="384"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="213.1751" y="388"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="90" x="120.1751" y="410.3027">opennms-db</text><!--entity portal-app--><rect fill="#FEFECE" filter="url(#fowbx44)" height="46.29" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="115" x="905.675" y="131"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="10" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="15" x="1000.675" y="136"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="998.675" y="138"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="998.675" y="142"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="75" x="920.675" y="164.3027">portal-app</text><!--entity portal-mongo--><rect fill="#FEFECE" filter="url(#fowbx44)" height="46.29" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="138" x="1034.18" y="254"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="10" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="15" x="1152.18" y="259"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="1150.18" y="261"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="1150.18" y="265"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="98" x="1049.18" y="287.3027">portal-mongo</text><!--entity portal-web--><rect fill="#FEFECE" filter="url(#fowbx44)" height="46.29" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="117" x="829.675" y="8"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="10" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="15" x="926.675" y="13"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="924.675" y="15"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="924.675" y="19"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="77" x="844.675" y="41.3027">portal-web</text><!--entity prometheus--><rect fill="#FEFECE" filter="url(#fowbx44)" height="46.29" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="123" x="284.675" y="131"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="10" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="15" x="387.675" y="136"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="385.675" y="138"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="385.675" y="142"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="83" x="299.675" y="164.3027">prometheus</text><!--entity rab_opennms--><rect fill="#FEFECE" filter="url(#fowbx44)" height="46.29" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="134" x="443.175" y="131"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="10" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="15" x="557.175" y="136"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="555.175" y="138"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="555.175" y="142"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="94" x="458.175" y="164.3027">rab_opennms</text><!--entity rabbitmq--><rect fill="#FEFECE" filter="url(#fowbx44)" height="46.29" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="103" x="648.675" y="377"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="10" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="15" x="731.675" y="382"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="729.675" y="384"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="729.675" y="388"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="63" x="663.675" y="410.3027">rabbitmq</text><path d="M433.159,420.981 C378.09,442.134 291.18,475.5186 232.489,498.0635 " fill="none" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.0; stroke-dasharray: 7.0,7.0;"/><polygon fill="#A80036" points="227.608,499.9386,237.4439,500.4428,232.275,498.1445,234.5733,492.9755,227.608,499.9386" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.0;"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="13" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="73" x="347.175" y="466.3525">depends on</text><path d="M444.27,300.002 C442.139,313.838 441.132,331.871 446.175,347 C449.216,356.123 454.554,364.935 460.323,372.631 " fill="none" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.0; stroke-dasharray: 7.0,7.0;"/><polygon fill="#A80036" points="463.561,376.787,461.1853,367.229,460.4881,372.8427,454.8744,372.1456,463.561,376.787" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.0;"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="13" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="73" x="447.175" y="343.3525">depends on</text><path d="M396.942,300.062 C383.193,307.877 369.372,317.826 359.175,330 C349.193,341.918 343.047,358.15 339.348,371.876 " fill="none" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.0; stroke-dasharray: 7.0,7.0;"/><polygon fill="#A80036" points="338.093,376.807,344.1886,369.0711,339.3258,371.9614,336.4356,367.0986,338.093,376.807" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.0;"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="13" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="73" x="360.175" y="343.3525">depends on</text><path d="M481.541,300.271 C503.41,314.728 533.276,333.348 561.175,347 C587.646,359.953 618.212,371.712 643.928,380.758 " fill="none" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.0; stroke-dasharray: 7.0,7.0;"/><polygon fill="#A80036" points="648.671,382.415,641.4933,375.6711,643.9506,380.7663,638.8554,383.2236,648.671,382.415" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.0;"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="13" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="73" x="562.175" y="343.3525">depends on</text><path d="M813.175,177.193 C813.175,197.405 813.175,227.307 813.175,248.919 " fill="none" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.0; stroke-dasharray: 7.0,7.0;"/><polygon fill="#A80036" points="813.175,253.947,817.175,244.947,813.175,248.947,809.175,244.947,813.175,253.947" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.0;"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="13" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="73" x="814.175" y="220.3525">depends on</text><path d="M792.449,300.193 C773.175,320.832 744.466,351.573 724.199,373.275 " fill="none" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.0; stroke-dasharray: 7.0,7.0;"/><polygon fill="#A80036" points="720.77,376.947,729.8363,373.0997,724.1828,373.2928,723.9896,367.6393,720.77,376.947" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.0;"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="13" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="73" x="764.175" y="343.3525">depends on</text><path d="M107.419,300.047 C72.9622,315.749 33.2533,340.602 13.1751,377 C-15.4127,428.823 52.5835,472.3619 107.899,497.8191 " fill="none" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.0; stroke-dasharray: 7.0,7.0;"/><polygon fill="#A80036" points="112.531,499.923,105.99,492.5599,107.9783,497.8558,102.6825,499.8442,112.531,499.923" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.0;"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="13" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="73" x="14.1751" y="404.8525">depends on</text><path d="M170.175,300.193 C170.175,320.405 170.175,350.307 170.175,371.919 " fill="none" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.0; stroke-dasharray: 7.0,7.0;"/><polygon fill="#A80036" points="170.175,376.947,174.175,367.947,170.175,371.947,166.175,367.947,170.175,376.947" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.0;"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="13" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="73" x="171.175" y="343.3525">depends on</text><path d="M170.175,423.193 C170.175,443.405 170.175,473.3072 170.175,494.9188 " fill="none" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.0; stroke-dasharray: 7.0,7.0;"/><polygon fill="#A80036" points="170.175,499.9474,174.175,490.9474,170.175,494.9474,166.175,490.9474,170.175,499.9474" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.0;"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="13" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="73" x="171.175" y="466.3525">depends on</text><path d="M988.853,177.193 C1012.83,197.917 1048.6,228.827 1073.72,250.544 " fill="none" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.0; stroke-dasharray: 7.0,7.0;"/><polygon fill="#A80036" points="1077.66,253.947,1073.469,245.0343,1073.8781,250.6764,1068.236,251.0854,1077.66,253.947" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.0;"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="13" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="73" x="1042.18" y="220.3525">depends on</text><path d="M955.446,177.06 C940.484,216.67 903.864,300.079 846.175,347 C820.523,367.865 785.855,380.68 756.738,388.367 " fill="none" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.0; stroke-dasharray: 7.0,7.0;"/><polygon fill="#A80036" points="751.743,389.65,761.4553,391.2845,756.5857,388.4058,759.4645,383.5362,751.743,389.65" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.0;"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="13" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="73" x="920.175" y="281.8525">depends on</text><path d="M861.526,54.041 C852.478,62.623 842.954,73.031 836.175,84 C828.322,96.707 822.815,112.404 819.164,125.614 " fill="none" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.0; stroke-dasharray: 7.0,7.0;"/><polygon fill="#A80036" points="817.806,130.731,823.9812,123.0585,819.0888,125.8984,816.2489,121.006,817.806,130.731" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.0;"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="13" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="73" x="837.175" y="97.3525">depends on</text><path d="M901.931,54.193 C914.565,74.576 933.307,104.813 946.727,126.464 " fill="none" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.0; stroke-dasharray: 7.0,7.0;"/><polygon fill="#A80036" points="949.506,130.947,948.1643,121.19,946.8718,126.6972,941.3646,125.4046,949.506,130.947" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.0;"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="13" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="73" x="930.175" y="97.3525">depends on</text><path d="M448.209,177.053 C388.38,198.345 298.068,230.485 236.735,252.312 " fill="none" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.0; stroke-dasharray: 7.0,7.0;"/><polygon fill="#A80036" points="232.002,253.997,241.8221,254.7488,236.7127,252.321,239.1406,247.2116,232.002,253.997" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.0;"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="13" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="73" x="361.175" y="220.3525">depends on</text><path d="M527.371,177.084 C562.397,222.064 641.875,324.13 679.583,372.555 " fill="none" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.0; stroke-dasharray: 7.0,7.0;"/><polygon fill="#A80036" points="682.881,376.79,680.5053,367.232,679.8081,372.8457,674.1944,372.1486,682.881,376.79" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.0;"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="13" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="73" x="621.175" y="281.8525">depends on</text></g></svg>
```

Comment: Do you know how to convert this listener on a Meteor template helper ?

Comment: @Jerome Sorry but that I do not know, I suggest you make a new question regarding this.